# How to install newest version of Minitube from Source

Tags: software-installation, minitube

I am very very unfamilar with installing from source, and the included INSTALL instructions are very vague and I tried following the commands but don't think all the proper info is given.

here is the primary instructions given.

> ### Prerequisites
>
> To compile Minitube you need at least Qt 4.5, Qt >= 4.6 is recommended.
>   The following Qt modules are needed: core, gui, network, xml, phonon, dbus
>
> On a Debian or Ubuntu system type:
>   sudo apt-get install build-essential qt4-dev-tools libphonon-dev
>
> ### Compiling
>
> Run:
>      $ qmake
>   and then:
>      $ make
>   Beware of the Qt3 version of qmake! If things go wrong try running qmake-qt4 instead.
>
> ### Running
>
> ./build/target/minitube
>
> ### A word about Phonon on Linux
>
> To be able to actually watch videos you need a working Phonon setup.
>   Please don't contact me about this, ask for help on your distribution support channels.
>
> ### Installing on Linux
>
> Run:
>      $ sudo make install
>   This is for packagers. End users should not install applications in this way.

The bold is simply because in the notes text file it has has marks for some reason. But to me this is very vague. I have the entire contents of the source file extracted into a "minitube" folder in my home dir. but I have tried running these qmake commands that are mentioned every way I can think of. And in every directory I can think of that makes sense. Still no use. And I'm not sure if I have the lastest version of Qt (4.5 or 4.6) installed as mentioned, not sure how to find out or how to upgrade as its not listed in my update manager.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Side note, I have already ran the most recent version of Minitube previous to this one with no issues for a long time installed with simple apt-get from ppa. So I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Thank you and God Bless.

Answer (score 0):

I've never even heard of Minitube, but I have written some Qt, so I'll try to help.

Since you're trying to build a Qt app, it may be advisable to just build the Qt source and link to that.  The latest version of Qt 4 is currently 4.8.5.  [Download the tar ball for Linux/X11](https://qt-project.org/downloads).  Follow [the instructions here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-x11.html) for building Qt for X11, very carefully.

When that is finished, your dependency problems (Qt dependencies anyway) should be gone.  Now you can run `qmake`.  `qmake` should be ran in the same directory as the `.pro` file for the project.  `qmake` will then build you a `Makefile` based on the instructions in the `.pro` file.  *You should not have to create this .pro file*, but if you can't find one anywhere then sometimes Qt can generate one for you by running `qmake -project`.  Note that this is a last resort only if there is no `.pro` already.  The default `.pro` will work sometimes, but only for simple projects.

After `qmake` finishes generating the `Makefile`, run make by simply typing `make`.  After make finishes building the target, you can run the executable by typing (from same directory) `./build/target/minitube`

To recap:

1. Build and install Qt for X11
2. Run `qmake` in the directory of the `.pro` file, or run `qmake -project` to generate a `.pro`, then run `qmake` on the `.pro`
3. Run `make`
4. Run the app with `./build/target/minitube`

Comment: Thank you, sorry took so long to get back to you, I havn't tried yet but will when I get time. Very busy today and tomorrow.

Thank you again Ben, and God Bless you!